# Woocommerce Stripe fee added incorrectly to Stripe Payout

Tags: php, woocommerce, stripe-payments

We have an article-writing service where clients can order articles by number of words. If more than 5000 words total are ordered (regardless how many articles), we apply a reduced rate. My adjusted price is calculated and appears fine when I'm on the individual Product page, Cart page, Checkout page, as well as throughout the backend.

But when I go to one specific area of the backend of Wordpress under Woocommerce > Orders > Edit Order, I see that the Stripe Fee is not being subtracted correctly from the product total price.

For example: You can see in the attached image below that -$3.76 is supposed to be subtracted from the order total of $80. The Stripe Payout should be $76.24 but instead displays as $115.43.

[image]

Below is the function I'm using to update the pricing. I've cobbled it together from online sources and it seems to be working fine (though probably not as efficiently as it could be) but I'm not exactly sure why the Stripe Payout value is incorrectly calculated.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'articles_alter_price_cart', 9999 );
 
function articles_alter_price_cart( $cart ) {

    $grandTotalWords = 0;
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
 
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ) return;

    /* Loop through cart items and get grand total of words */
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $qty = $cart_item['quantity'];
        $wordsPerArticle = $cart_item['variation']['attribute_number-of-words'];
        $numWords = $wordsPerArticle * $qty;
        $grandTotalWords += $numWords;
    }

    /* Update cart item prices based on grand total of words */
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        $qty = $cart_item['quantity'];
        $numWordsInput = $cart_item['variation']['attribute_number-of-words'];
        $arr = explode(' Words', $numWordsInput);
        $wordsPerArticle = $arr[0];

        $numWords = $wordsPerArticle * $qty;

        if ( $grandTotalWords != '' && $grandTotalWords > 0 ) {
            if ( $grandTotalWords > 10000 ) {
                $totalCost = $numWords * 0.125;
            } elseif ( $grandTotalWords >= 5000 && $grandTotalWords <= 10000 ) {
                $totalCost = $numWords * 0.15;
            } else {
                $totalCost = $numWords * 0.2;
            }
        }

        $singleCost = $totalCost / $qty;
        /* Tried setting type as string because totals are saved as strings apparently  */
        settype($singleCost, 'string');

        $cart_item['data']->set_price( $singleCost );
    }
 
}
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you increase the `2` to, say, `3` or `5` in `if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ) return;` does it resolve the issue?  My guess is that the particular area you're looking at in WooCommerce is triggering that early return and preventing the rest of the code from running.

Comment: @JustinMichael I just tested with both values and no luck. It was a $40 transaction with a Stripe fee of -$2.03 which resulted in $57.57 Stripe Payout.